# Sublime auto fold the code

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, fold

By default when I open file it looks as follows:

[image]

And I want always unfold when I open a file

[image]

Is there any keybinding exist that can unfold everything automatically not require any command from keyboar ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you last saved a file while it was folded, Sublime will remember that. Select **`Edit -> Code Folding -> Unfold All`**, make a small change like adding then deleting a space, then resave the file. It will open unfolded next time.

Also, as a point of style, *please* use 4 spaces for indentation. Using 1 space, it's almost impossible to differentiate the various indentation levels. 2 spaces is almost as bad. With a Python file open, select **`Preferences -> Settings-More -> Syntax-Specific - User`** and add the following:

```js
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```